# How to get a simple CSV text column from a multidimension array column in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

This data is in a column called Triggers.

```
[{"item": "Pollution", "type": "Asthma trigger", "user_entered_item": false}, {"item": "Emotions", "type": "Asthma trigger", "user_entered_item": false}]
```

I want to end with a column called Triggers_Simple

```
Pollution, Emotions
```

So going form a MD array to a text column (CSV)

I am basically selecting all the values from the key "item" from the "Triggers" column.

Comment: 1) That looks like a JSON array with objects not a Postgres array type. You need to provide more information about the `type` of the field this data is being stored in. 2) A CSV is a file format, you want a text string in a `text/varchar` field, correct? The difference being CSV would be `Pollution, Emotions` and you are going to end up with `'Pollution, Emotions'`.

Comment: Yes the column is a JSON array and the end result will be a text. By CSV I just mean I want a coma separated list of values in the text string.

Comment: @Matt2012 What exactly is the type of the column, `jsonb`? Or `json`? Or `json[]`? Best provide the table definition as SQL code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements` to iterate the array, `->>` to access an object property and get back a text, and `string_agg` to join the strings together by a comma separator. Put the whole thing in a subquery:

```
SELECT (
  SELECT string_agg(value->>'item', ', ')
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(triggers)
) AS triggers_simple
FROM example;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JmgtzvtT))</sup>